# Trying to understand more about bitset in c++

Tags: c++, string, bitset

I was trying to understand more about using bitset to convert a string into binary then transfer it into another string rather then just cout straight. I will always receive an exception error "Unhandled exception at 0x773D3DB2 C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x006FF800.
" using visual studio 2017 may i know why?

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{

   std::string hello = "C";
   std::string yellow;
   for (auto character : hello)
   {
    yellow += std::bitset<7>(hello).to_string();
    cout << yellow;
    return 0;
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `std::bitset<7>(hello)` and not `std::bitset<7>(character)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are guilty of not having warnings enabled for your compiler, or using a compiler not capable of warning you that the variable `character` is not used in your loop.

Change

```
yellow += std::bitset<7>(hello).to_string();
```

to

```
yellow += std::bitset<7>(character).to_string();
```

Output:

```
1000011
```

Also, note that you don't actually *loop*, because your loop `return`s on its first iteration. I assume that your code example has gone through several iterations of trial & error by this point...

Comment: Hi Devsolar, thanks for the feedback. I will look into it

Comment: i guess i was guilty that i didn't understand fully the concept behind using the ranged loop that i missed out using character instead of hello. Thanks for pointing it out to me guys

Comment: @FunSherwin: The meta help in this answer is: *Always run your compiler in the strictest warning mode possible.* The compiler is your friend. Even if a warning does not point out an outright error, *not* having that warning pop up is a good thing and a sign of code quality. FWIW, that loop should add to `yellow`, but only print what was *added* this loop, not the whole of `yellow` (this should become obvious once `hello` has more than one character). And you should only `return` *after* the loop, not from inside it (for the same reason).